# error page occurs while accessing buy link of Google books API result

Tags: android, google-api, barcode-scanner, google-books

i am doing a bar code scanner application.I am trying to get Google book details from the bar code ISBN number in android application. Also i got all the book details from API result successfully. But if i try to access the buy link from API result, i am unable to access the buy link of the book. It says 404 error. Can anyone help me, how to access the buy link to buy a book.? Thanks in advance.

Here is the buy link of book got from below result:

http://books.google.co.in/books?id=xqxBtXmxqV4C&dq=isbn:9781849699327&hl=&buy=&source=gbs_api

Here is the API result:

```
"saleInfo": {
"country": "IN",
"saleability": "FOR_SALE",
"isEbook": true,
"listPrice": {
 "amount": 162.0,
 "currencyCode": "INR"
},
"retailPrice": {
 "amount": 113.4,
 "currencyCode": "INR"
},
"buyLink": "http://books.google.co.in/books?id=xqxBtXmxqV4C&dq=isbn:9781849699327&hl=&buy=&source=gbs_api",
"offers": [
 {
  "finskyOfferType": 1,
  "listPrice": {
   "amountInMicros": 1.62E8,
   "currencyCode": "INR"
  },
  "retailPrice": {
   "amountInMicros": 1.134E8,
   "currencyCode": "INR"
  }
 }
]
```

Comment: do you post your log cat?

Comment: In log cat it shows no error and no run time error also. If i try to access the link from browser, it shows the 404 page error.There may be some country restrictions. How can i access that link from india.?

Comment: do you post the link please i can test bez i am also from great INDIA

Comment: I have posted the link.. can u check?

Comment: Hai Sreekanthss. Did u check the link.?

Comment: how you get that link? i think there is some thing wrong with the URl. are you trying to search for Instant Html5 Local Storage How-To book??

Comment: http://books.google.co.in/books?id=xqxBtXmxqV4C&dq=isbn:9781849699327&source=gbs_api working and i feel you are missing &hl=& buy= that cause error

Comment: in that you are missing &hl=& buy=, test with out that works

Comment: @Sreekanthss: I am getting the buy link of a specific book from it's ISBN number. By using the ISBN number along with the URL i can get the google books API result. From the result i can get the buy link of book. Here is the link. https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:9781849699327